# Restful webservice with a c++ backend service / daemon

Tags: web-services, rest, httpservice

We have a native service / daemon in written C++. We are looking to provide a Restful web-service to control / setup the service.
Assuming that the web-service is either implemented in .Net or Java, what is the best way to communicate with the native service / daemon.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is very broad, have you tried to search on this site for possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, I searched on StackOverflow but didn't find anything. I did try to keep the question to the point. All I am looking for is the options for the webservice and a backend native service / demon to communicate. Let me know if you still think if its too broad.